# A few questions regarding the Facebook like button on external websites

Tags: facebook, facebook-like

I am working on a project where I need to manipulate the button in a few ways.

1. Is it possible to just have the button and not the 'X people like this' text after it?
2. Does it have to be for one's own page or can it be easily configured, e.g. can I have a button that when clicked likes the fan page for Coca-Cola?
3. If so, is it possible to get the pop up when you hover over the button, like the pages down the left hand side on https://www.facebook.com/Google

Thanks very much in advance for your help. Please let me know if I have been unclear.

Answer (score 0):

1. You could try the `button_layout` layout, which just has the little speech bubble with the number of likers. If you don't like that, you can cut that bubble off by setting the width of the parent container to less than the width of the button.
2. You can use whatever page URL or web page URL you want.
3. Hovercards aren't available on fb:like right now, but might be at some point.

[More documentation here.](http://developers.facebook.com/docs/reference/plugins/like/)